# Append Answer (li tag) to respective Questio (ul tag)

Tags: jquery, html, loops, append, each

I am trying to make a dynamic Question & Answer form.

Basically I have inputs that are generated like so

```
<input id="Question-1" class="question"></input>
<input id="Q1-Answer-1" class="answer"></input>
<input id="Q1-Answer-2" class="answer"></input>

<input id="Question-2" class="question"></input>
<input id="Q2-Answer-1" class="answer"></input>
<input id="Q2-Answer-2" class="answer"></input>
```

The user can add or remove questions, answers as much as they desire.
Now, when a function is called, all the question's value should be inside **ul** with their according **li** answers.

I can't seem to figure out how to make a proper loop as all the questions are appended to all the questions.

Any help?

Broken code:

```
function outputHTML(){
    var arrQ= new Array();
    var arrA= new Array();
    var n = $( ".result-q" ).length +1;


    $('.input-question').each(function(n){
        arrQ.push("<ul id='result-question-"+(n+1)+"' class='result-q'>"+$(this).val()+"</ul>");
    });


    $('.answer').each(function(a) {
        var ans = $(this).find('.input-answer');
        arrA.push("<li class='result-question-"+(n+1)+"'>"+$(ans).val()+"</li>");
        arrA.appendTo(result)
    });


    $("#results").append(arrQ);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
outputHTML();

function outputHTML() {
    var results = '';
    $('.question')
        .each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var questionNumber = $this.attr('id').split('-')[1];
            results += "<ul id='result-question-"+ questionNumber +"' class='result-q'>" + $this.val() + getAnswer(questionNumber) + "</ul>";
        });
    $('#results').html(results);
}

function getAnswer(questionNumber) {
    var answer = '';
    $('input[id^=Q' + questionNumber + '].answer')
        .each(function(){
            answer += "<li class='result-question-" + questionNumber +"'>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
    });
    return answer;
}
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/beginnerCF/fryetz8r/).

Comment: This worked wonderfully!

Thank you very much :)

One more thing, I have a radio button related issue.

Let's say "Question1-Answer2" is checked and "Question2-Answer1" is checked. How could I have this affect the CSS class of the answer?

Comment: @y4my4m Better ask another question for that.